# How to create individual tableviews for items in an array?

Tags: swift

My app has a number of rooms in a tableview, pictures below, when the user taps on a room, it segue's to a separate view which is also a table view ,
pictured below.

I would like to display individual checklists within each of these views, however the code I have entered does not display the array items, see below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (roomCheckList.count)
}

private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = roomList[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell
    
}
```

How do I create individual checklists for each item when the user selects it from the main screen?

Once created, how do I save these items, so when the user revisits the screen, they have not disappeared?

[image: Home Screen]

[image: Individual view]

Comment: You have to change your model to a struct to include also the *array items* and pass the  item at index path in `prepare(for segue` to the detail controller.

Answer (score 1):

Considering maintainability, how about this approach?

```
enum CellType: Int {
　　case aCell
　　case bCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  guard let cellType = CellType(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return UITableViewCell() }
  switch cellType {
  　　case .aCell:
  　　　　// configure the Acell

  　　case .bCell:
  　　　　// configure the Bcell

　　  default
　　     // configure the other cells
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which I saw in different projects: configure each cell based on its **index** in **cellForRowAt()**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //configure the cell
   } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        //configure the cell
   }
   // configure the other cells
}
```